# The Insert statement conflict with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

my models are as follows...

```
public class Company
{


    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }

    public bool HasFuneralInsuranceParlours { get; set; }
    public bool HasFuneralInsurancePolicies { get; set; }
    public bool HasLifeInsurancePolicies { get; set; }


    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Office> Offices { get; set; }
}


public class Office
{

   [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Address3 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Fax { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Companies { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

}
```

and controllers

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Create(OfficeModel model)
    {

        bool success = false;
        string message = "";
        byte[] logo = null;

        var user = SecurityHelper.GetAuthenticatedUser(this.HttpContext);
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.Name.IsNullOrWhitespace()) throw new Exception("Unable to create this Employee Name. The Type cannot be blank or spaces.");
                if (models.Offices.Any(x => x.Name.ToLower() == model.Name.ToLower())) throw new Exception(string.Format("This Office's Name '{0}' already exists. Please check your data.", model.Name.ToUpperCase()));


                var entry = new Office
                {
                    Id  = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Name = model.Name.ToUpperCase(),
                    Address1 = model.Address1.ToUpperCase(),
                    Address2 = model.Address2.ToUpperCase(),
                    Address3 = model.Address3.ToUpperCase(),
                    Telephone = model.Telephone.ToUpperCase(),
                    Fax = model.Fax.ToUpperCase(),
                    Email = model.Email.ToUpperCase(),
                    IsDeleted = false,
                    CompanyId = user.CompanyId,

                    Bankings =  new List<Banking>()
                    {
                        new Banking
                        {
                            Bank = model.OfficeBank.ToUpperCase(),
                            Account = model.BankAccount.ToUpperCase(),
                            Branch = model.Branch.ToUpperCase(),
                            BranchNo = model.BranchNo.ToUpperCase(),
                            AccountType = model.AccountType.ToUpperCase()
                        }
                    }
                };
                models.Offices.Add(entity);
                success = true;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                message = "An error was cought please check your data and retry";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

when l debug the above code l return the following error

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.Offices_dbo.Companies_CompanyId\". The conflict occurred in
>   database  \"PolicyManager\", table \"dbo.Companies\", column
>   'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

When l hover model.Name l am return a value but the rest return me a null value which l suspect the thus the cause of the the above error.

What problem can it possible be because l have used the similar code before and it worked. May anyone help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Could it be that there's already a problem with the `user` var? I.e. `user.CompanyId` has no value (or not the right one)?

Comment: What is `Bankings`? What is `entity`? Shouldn't it be models.Offices.Add(entry)?;

Comment: yes banking is an entity which holds banking details..

Comment: @ThomasWeller l'm still getting the same error when comment out var user and companyId.

Comment: Of course you do! You need to inspect it while debugging!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding a New Office.

The error says that there is a referential integrity problem With the Foreign key constraint to the Company table.

When you create the Order you add the following Company key:

```
CompanyId = user.CompanyId
```

So it appears that user.CompanyId is not an id that is registered against an existing Company.